# window.addEventListener works only after a refresh

Tags: javascript, html, function

I need a little help for one function which is working only after a refresh. I`m not experienced with javascript and i need just to add one small "div" to already compliled project.

The index.html is

```
... 
<body>
<script src="runtime-es2015-container.js" type="module">
<script src="runtime-es5-container.js" nomodule defer>
<script src="polyfils-es-5.js" defer>

<script>
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 setTimeout(() => {
   let envContainer = document.querySelector('.info');
   envContainer.setAttribute('style', 'flex-direction:column:');
   let envRow = document.createElement('div');
   envRow.classList.add('instance');
   envContainer.appendChild(envRow).innerText = 'some text ';
   },100);
 }
 ....
```

The functional is working only after refreshing the page. I gues the problem is with selecting the  '.info' , which is loaded before the function is executed.

Thanks,
Svetoslav

Comment: You are missing a closing string on `envContainer.setAttribute` function call, *your second argument ends with `)` instead of `'`*.

Comment: My fault i copied wrongly . In the code is with ' in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made a testrun of this and it seem to be working just fine, the only thing that was missing from your code was a ) in the end..

To me it looks like your problem is elsewhere. Well unless the info object is not created by code, then the problem is that it does not yet exist when you run this code..

--- Update ---
OKay so the div is created by js code and you have to wait for it.. the best idea I have is to poll and wait for it, I have updated the example to do just that and also changed to code to create the div after the first run of the function to simulate your situation.

```js
function update_info() {
  if(document.querySelector('.info')) {
   let envContainer = document.querySelector('.info');
   envContainer.setAttribute('style', 'flex-direction:column:');
   let envRow = document.createElement('div');
   envRow.classList.add('instance');
   envContainer.appendChild(envRow).innerText = 'some text ';
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      update_info();
    },100);
  }
}  

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  update_info();
  const infodiv = document.createElement('div')
  infodiv.id = "info";
  infodiv.classList.add("info")
  infodiv.innerHTML = "this first div";
  document.body.appendChild(infodiv);
})
```

```html
<body>
```

Comment: yes, Griffin this actually is the problem. The info div is added  dynamically from javascript (not sure) , but when the function is executed the 'info' div looks like is not loaded and the function just not work. I tried to extend the timeout, but looks still not working. Maybe there is a way to execute this function on the very last moment after everything else is executed on the page ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Griffin. Based on your answer it is working.
I just deleted those line 

const infodiv = document.createElement('div')
  infodiv.id = "info";
  infodiv.classList.add("info")
  infodiv.innerHTML = "this first div";
  document.body.appendChild(infodiv);

Answer (score 1):

I see you have some errors in the code, try using this code which i fixed and changed a little bit and let me know if it works

```
<script>
 window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 setTimeout(() => {
   let envContainer = document.querySelector('.info');
   envContainer.setAttribute('style', 'flex-direction:column');
   let envRow = document.createElement('div');
   envRow.classList.add('instance');
   envContainer.appendChild(envRow).innerText = 'some text ';
   },100);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi ,i`ve changed it but still it is loading only after a reloading the page

Comment: I think i don't undertand your question clearly, like what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: i want to append one div to an existing one after loading the page.

Comment: Can you attach a codepen of the code you have?

Comment: I cannot attach a codepen ,since the project is complied and there are two many files and i cannot isolate the showcase. The idea is to getting the exising div and append it another one  with hardcoded values